# C# - After adding web browser to from, I can't start it?

Tags: c#

So I am using "Theme" on my C# Form which is called "Flat UI". After I added Web Browser to my form I can't start it error what I am getting is:

> 'System.NullReferenceException - Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

And it is pointing here: `ParentForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` on my `FormSkin.cs` Does anyone know solution to fix it?

Full C#

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
    base.OnCreateControl();
    ParentForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    ParentForm.ControlBox = false;
    ParentForm.AllowTransparency = false;
    ParentForm.TransparencyKey = Color.Fuchsia;
    ParentForm.FindForm().StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: It seems `ParentForm` is not initialized properly before invoking the above statement.Please check wether its initialized properly or not.

Comment: If I may ask how could I check that?

Comment: You can debug ur code and put a cursor over the `ParentForm` variable, if it shows `null` it's not initialzed.

Comment: It seems to be null yep, how could I initialize it properly?

Comment: if the `ParentForm` does not have any parameters in constructor then you can initialize as `ParentForm parentForm = new ParentForm();`

Comment: I edited my first post, maybe it's better.